# Further information about Er

Tags: genesis

[Genesis 38:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2038:7) (NIV edition of the Bible) states the following:

> But Er, Judah’s firstborn, was wicked in the Lord’s sight; so the Lord put him to death.

I would like to know a bit more about Er's behavior. **Is there any reference (different from the Bible) where I could learn about him and about this verse?**